# Ionic: App crashed on Splash Screen (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am developing an app on IONIC framework.
The app used to run fine on both the OS (Android & iOS),
But since last few days the app does not runs on the iPhone.
The app crashes on the splash screen(iOS).
I remember of not changing anything in the config.xml.

> confix.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="a.b.c" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>Project Name</name>
<description>
    An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
</description>
<author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
    Your Name Here
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splashscreen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-ipad.png" width="167" />
</platform>
<!-- <icon src="resources/splash.png" /> -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git" />
```

> List of plugins I am using:

1. cordova-plugin-device
2. cordova-plugin-dialogs
3. cordova-plugin-geolocation
4. cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
5. cordova-plugin-network-information
6. cordova-plugin-splashscreen
7. cordova-plugin-statusbar
8. cordova-plugin-whitelist
9. cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
10. cordova-plugin-x-toast
11. cordova-sqlite-storage
12. ionic-plugin-keyboard
13. mx.ferreyra.callnumber
14. phonegap-facebook-plugin
15. uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator

I have already tried removing and re installing the iOS platform,
removing and re installing the cordova-plugin-splashscreen

In my app.js I am hiding the splash screen.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
$timeout(function() {
            $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
        }, 3000);
});
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: try deleting ios folder and `ionic run ios`, make sure all the plugins are installed.

Comment: What kind of crash? Do you have a backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the platform 
`ionic cordova platform rm ios`

and then re-adding it

`ionic cordova platform add ios`

You can also check the console of Xcode for more information about the crashing.